# Blank Page When Reload (Unexpected token '<'" : Firebase Hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, create-react-app

I deployed my React project on Firebase and the page reload causes a problem. When I open the deployed link the website appears fine, but when I reload the page, a blank page appears and in the console displays 304 error with "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'". Refreshing the page in development works. What can be the cause?

I feel like it has something to do with Routes but I'm not sure...

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <Route path='/' exact>
        {!authCtx.loggedIn && (
          <Redirect to='/bug-tracker/login' exact>
            <Login />
          </Redirect>
        )}
        {authCtx.loggedIn && (
          <Redirect to='/bug-tracker/bugs-list' exact>
            <Sidebar className={classes.sidebar} />
            <BugsList className={classes.bugslist} />
          </Redirect>
        )}
      </Route>
      {!authCtx.loggedIn && (
        <Route path='/bug-tracker/login' exact>
          <Login />
        </Route>
      )}
      {authCtx.loggedIn && (
        <div className={classes.container}>
          <Sidebar className={classes.sidebar} />
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/bug-tracker/bugs-list' exact>
              <BugsList className={classes.bugslist} />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/bug-tracker/bugs-list/:bugId'>
              <BugItemDetail className={classes['bug-detail']} />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/bug-tracker/submit-bug'>
              <AddNewBug className={classes['submit-bug']} />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/bug-tracker/update-bug/:bugId'>
              <UpdateBug className={classes['update-bug']} />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      )}
      {!authCtx.token && (
        <Redirect to='/bug-tracker/login' exact>
          <Login />
        </Redirect>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Most of the time, this error means that the directory path is wrong. Did you double check the `index.html`, `app.js` if it's really set and working?

Comment: I think it's working. I didn't change after I used create-react-app so the index.html is in the public folder and the App.js is in the src folder (sorry if this isn't what you meant...)

Answer (score 4):

I fixed my problem. Below was my setting in package.json. I was leaving it because it worked when I deployed another project to Netlify.

**"homepage": "."**

Removing this line completely sort of helped to solve the issue with reloading... Now reloading on any page works fine.

Comment: I deploy in Netlify always without `homepage` property because it can cause this issue indeed.

TIP: If you deploy a project in Netlify with `react-router-dom`, in order to allow refresh the pages without errors you should create a `_redirects` file inside the `public` folder. inside this page put a code to allow refresh.

`/* /index.html 200`

Example: https://github.com/coffezilla/react-router-protected/tree/master/react-app/public

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I should review my Netlify project too so it won't cause any problem...

Comment: Nice job! Helped me with a React app hosted on Firebase! Thnx